How to create conda env with special proprietary Python from specific location?
I have some proprietary software from SomeCompany (TM) that allows python scripting, but for that one has to use their own special version of python, which is attached to the rest of proprietary files. Let's call it "proppython.exe" in the path C:\programs\SomeCompany\software\scripting\proppython.exe.
I want to create a conda environment that would use that proppython instead of any usual python.
I used the following command in the Pycharm's terminal:
conda create -n "myenv" python=C:\programs\SomeCompany\software\scripting\proppython.exe
But I got SyntaxError.
So how do I replace the usual python with this specific one? My tool of work is Pycharm and conda.
I already have read the F manual, but it doesn't offer that much help with scripting.

Try this https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/

Conda installs a new copy of python for each virtual environment.  But those files come from the anaconda repo, not a local file.
You might be able to create a virtual environment with the same Python version, and then copy the proprietary Python file into the new environment.
first get the version
C:\programs\SomeCompany\software\scripting\proppython.exe -V
# Python 3.8.7

Then create a conda environment that matches the version, activate and get the location of the conda environment
conda create -n work-env python=3.8 -y
conda activate work-env
echo %CONDA_PREFIX%
# C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\work-env

Then copy the python files into the new environment:
copy C:\programs\SomeCompany\software\scripting\*python* C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\work-env

Finally, rename the proppython.exe to python.exe:
mv C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\work-env\proppython.exe C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\work-env\python.exe

Again, this might not work at all.  But you can try.
